# Can I set Kusto cluster from config file?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Does anybody have experience with setting the cluster name in a Kusto query from a config file? For example,

```
cluster(Config.clusterName).database('sample').MyTable
```

Or is the cluster name always hard-coded? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you are using is "cross cluster query" meaning you can run it when connecting you another cluster. If you don't need specifically this syntax, you can read the connectionstring where you are running the query from config file, for example:

```
var serviceUri = Config.clusterUri
var authority = "contoso.com"; // Or the AAD tenant GUID: "..."

// Recommended syntax
var kustoConnectionStringBuilder = new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(serviceUri)
  .WithAadUserPromptAuthentication(authority);
```

If you need the cross cluster query and want to read the connection string from config file, you can add the query with some template to replace (like {0}) and replace it using string.format for instance before running the query

```
MyQuery join (cluster({0}).database('sample').MyTable)
```

Answer (score 1):

The cluster name must be a constant string, for security reasons.